# share.streamlit can't find pkl file

Tags: python, pickle, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that works perfectly well on localhost. However, when deployed to share.streamlit, the FileNotFoundError constantly pop up
I have already changed the app to use Python 3.9 (which is the same version I am using on my local machine).
Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/leminhds/breast-cancer-diabetes-and-liver-disease-predictor
and here is the link to the app: https://share.streamlit.io/leminhds/breast-cancer-diabetes-and-liver-disease-predictor/app/app.py

Any help would be appreciated since I have been spending the past hours trying different combination of renaming the path, relocating the pkl file, but nothing work. Thank you

Comment: Can you copy paste the exact error messsage in here? So what file are we talking about? Maybe look into the logs history within streamlit share. Also make sure you have all the necassary python modules listed in your requirements.txt file on github.

Comment: the error message is: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'liver_model.pkl' despite the fact that the file exist. All the modules are also listed in requirements.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came from the fact that I was using relative path. When upload to Share.streamlit, it doesn't work anymore.

To overcome this problem, I simply use the pathlib module to find the root of the folder on github. Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

pkl_path = Path(__file__).parents[1] / 'pages/liver_model.pkl'
```

Comment: I'm facing the same error. Could you explain a little bit more how is this working.